# How to use $this in another file on Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a file named `fn.php` in my view, then I create a function to post data, like this

```
function post($input_name){
   return $this->input->post($input_name);
}
```

In my controller I call it like this,

```
public function myFunc(){
   $this->input->load('fn.php');
   // then I use the function that I have created like this
   post('myinputname');
}
```

But... I got error, how I can solve this problem? thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take some time to try and understand the MVC architecture. It is, after all, one of the main points of using a framework.

You can't put functions in a view and expect to load them somehow and access them. You can put functions in a model, controller, library or helper. In you case I would suggest a helper:

`application/helpers/some_file_helper.php`

```
function post($input_name){
   $CI = &get_instance();
   return $CI->input->post($input_name);
}
```

The `get_instance()` part is only used when `$this` (CI context) isn't available. *This only happens in helpers and libraries.* In views, controllers, and models `$this` is always available.

Model or controller:

```
$this->load->helper('some_file');

print_r(post('somevar'));
```

However if all you want to do is access the post variable use `$this->input->post('somevar')` directly and don't introduce an extra layer.